# Jest test for async promise with async/await

Tags: javascript, testing, async-await, jestjs

I have this function that returns a promise and fails when is called:

```js
export const mockAsync = () => {
  return new Promise((_, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('Error')), 50);
  });
};
```

And I have this test, which is passing:

```js
describe('mockAsync', () => {
  test('it should throw if we ask for it', async () => {
    const result = mockAsync();

    await expect(result).rejects.toThrow('Error');
  });
});
```

But I find it weird, I would expect it to call `await` before the function call:

```js
describe('mockAsync', () => {
  test('it should throw if we ask for it', async () => {
    const result = await mockAsync();

    expect(result).rejects.toThrow('Error');
  });
});
```

This last one is not passing, and I cant understand why. Is not the correct syntax?

Comment: If you `await mockAsync()`, the rejected promise _throws as an error_. That's nothing to do with Jest, it's how the syntax works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the test the work you want the promise to be rejected within the context of the expect.
for that reason we usually write it like this:

```
await expect(/*sync function call*/).rejects.toThrow('someError')
```

And in your particular example:

```
describe('mockAsync', () => {
    test('it should throw if we ask for it', async () => {

        await expect(mockAsync()).rejects.toThrow('Error')
    })
})
```

If you want to use the Try/Catch approach simply catch the error and make sure the error is the expected one:

```
describe('mockAsync', () => {
    test('it should throw if we ask for it', async () => {

        try{
            await mockAsync()
        }
        catch(err){
            expect(err.message).toEqual('Error')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Now I get it, as it throws we need to be withing the `expect` context, or within a `throw/catch` statement

Comment: correct. in the try/catch scenario you will not use the expect().rejects way, you will simply expect the error you caught in the catch to equal the error you are expecting

Comment: May you add a try/catch example? Just for reference

Comment: @EmilleC. read the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous

Comment: @jonrsharpe great advice, except it isn't.

Comment: @EmilleC. no? It shows numerous testing scenarios, _including_ both the .rejects and try/catch versions of the rejected promise case.

Comment: They don't mention the scope of the throw, which is not obvious.

Comment: @EmilleC. I added a try/catch option